# Linear algebra with a sparse triagonol marix

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a tridiagonal matrix A which I want to make a sparse matrix and then solve a linear system Ax =b using scipy, how is this done.

i have tried the following code, which dosent work.

```py
from scipy.sparse import dia_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve_triangular

N = 10


diag = np.zeros(N) + 2
udiag = np.zeros(N) + 1
A = dia_matrix(([diag, udiag, udiag], [0, 1, -1]), shape=(N, N))


b = np.ones(N)

print(A.todense())
print(b)


x = spsolve_triangular(A, b)

print(x)
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Do you mean diagonal matrix or tridiagonal matrix ?

Comment: ups yes tridiagonal, didnt know that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that your matrix is not triangular but tridiagonal. As such you have to use the [spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve) function instead of the spsolve_triangular function.